# How index a varchar virtual generated column in MariaDB?

Tags: indexing, mariadb

I need to use indexing to query a varchar virtual generated column from a JSON column, but I'm not sure why the index is not being used. Is it because of the varchar type?

Table DDL

```
create table dp_order
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    detail longtext collate utf8mb4_bin default '{}' not null,
    phone_number varchar(20) as (json_value(`detail`, '$.phone_number')),
    constraint detail check (json_valid(`detail`))
)

create index dp_order_phone_number
    on dp_order (phone_number);
```

Query

```
EXPLAIN
(SELECT *
 FROM dp_order
 WHERE phone_number = '081234567890');
```

Result

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,dp_order,ALL,dp_order_phone_number,,,,34,Using where
```

MariaDB version `10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~focal`

Comment: What about `select id from...` - does that use your index?

Comment: that's worked! I guess the index is affected by the other column if I use the wildcard(?), since I don't include them all in the DDL.
anw thankyou @Stu